# How to Access Google Drive in Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, google-drive, jupyter

I've just installed a dual boot of ubuntu on my XPS15. I want to use this as a development environment for python as I've had many issues using windows and I was told that this was the best solution.

I can't seem to access Google Drive (where all my learning notebooks are stored) in Jupyter on Ubuntu like I could on windows. Does any know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The jupyter-drive project is no longer supported due to the deprecation of the Google Realtime API.

You might instead consider [jupyterlab/jupyterlab-google-drive](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-google-drive); which adds a Google Drive file browser to the left sidebar of JupyterLab.

> This repository contains custom Contents classes that allows IPython
> to use Google Drive for file management. The code is organized as a
> python package that contains functions to install a Jupyter Notebook
> JavaScript extension, and activate/deactivate different IPython
> profiles to be used with Google drive.
>
> To install this package, run:
>
> ```
> git clone git://github.com/jupyter/jupyter-drive.git  
> pip3 install -e jupyter-drive
> ```
>
> This will install the package in editable mode with pip, which
> means that any change you make to the repository will be reflected
> into the importable version immediately.
>
> To install the notebook extension and activate your configuration with
> Google Drive, run:
>
> ```
> python3 -m jupyterdrive
> ```
>
> To deactivate, run:
>
> ```
> python3 -m jupyterdrive --deactivate
> ```
>
> **First launch**
>
> Launch IPython with the profile in which you activated jupyter-drive:
>
> ```
> ipython notebook --profile <profilename>
> ```
>
> On first launch, the application will ask you for the authorization to
> access your files on Google Drive. It only asks for permission to
> create new files or to access files it has created or that you
> manually open with this application. It also requires permission to
> access file/directory metadata, in order to display the list of
> files/directories in the tree view.
>
> The request pop-up looks like the following:
>
> [image]
>
> Clicking **OK** will open a Google OAuth pop-up. You will see that the
> Jupyter Drive application wants access to some information about your
> files. Keep that in mind if you want to revoke access at a later
> point.
>
> [image]
>
> Once you click **Accept** you should be able to start creating new
> notebooks on Google Drive, and open existing ones created by this
> application, and view files/directories in the tree view.

Comment: Hi, on ubuntu 20.04, it says no module named jupyterdrive. when I run: python -m jupyterdrive

Comment: @XinNiu Try `python3 -m jupyterdrive`